# Gitlhub access token not working '$GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN

Tags: python, shell, gitlab, private-key

Hope someone can help me on this.
I wrote an API in .SH to get a message details.

```
curl --silent -k --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN"** *and some code*
```

Here, when hardc-oding the `PRIVATE-TOKEN`, the script is working fine but when I'm using this variable its not working.

Can anyone suggest why this happens and what can be the possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would check first if the variable is correctly set:

```
echo "GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN='${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}'"
```

Note the simple quotes around `${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}`: it helps visualizing if there is any extra space after the token, which could be problematic.

Then I would use the `${}` syntax, to be safe:

```
curl --silent -k --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}"
```

I would also do the same command with `--verbose` instead of `--silent`, in order to *see* what `curl` is doing (for testing).

Note the space between `PRIVATE-TOKEN:` and the token.
See [GitLab API / Personal/project access tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#personalproject-access-tokens)

> Example of using the personal or project access token in a parameter:
>
> ```
> curl "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=<your_access_token>"
> ```
>
> Example of using the personal or project access token in a header:
>
> ```
> curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects"
> ```
>
> You can also use personal or project access tokens with OAuth-compliant headers:
>
> ```
> curl --header "Authorization: Bearer <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects"
> ```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't worked. Issue is still there

Comment: Does the echo work? Does it display the correct value for the token?

Comment: No, it's returning blank. Maybe because of security issue

Comment: @Rio OK. As long asit is not correctly set, it will cause the issue.

Comment: No, maybe because of security reasons its not displaying the token

Comment: @Rio Why? A shell script will display any variable you want: what is your runtime environment? Is it something executed in a GitLab pipeline on a remote GitLab server? Your question does not specify where it runs.

Comment: It runs in pipeline

Comment: @Rio All the examples I can find mention you have to set that variable: it is not set for you by the pipeline.